# Dominance in Data Envelopment analysis in R

Tags: r, benchmarking

I need to formalise in R the following rule, called dominance:

`(x1,y1)` dominates `(x2,y2)` if and only if `x1<=x2`(1) and `y1>=y2`(2) and `(x1,y1) different from (x2,y2)`(3).

x and y are vectors containing several variables. I have tried the following:

```
i1 = (min(x1)<=min(x2) && max(y1)>=max(y2))
```

where `i1` is a boolean which will give me a TRUE if `x1` dominates `x2` indeed, a FALSE if not.

However I struggle to implement (3), which is when 1 and 2 are equal for both x and y.

Comment: `min(x1)<=min(x2) && max(y1)>=max(y2)) && !(x1==x2 && y1==y2)` maybe like this

Comment: Are `x1`, `x2`, etc scalars or vectors?

Comment: they are vectors

Comment: If they are vectors, use pmax and pmin.